# why aren't clojure strings of type clojure.string?

Tags: clojure

Just curious on why a string in Clojure isn't of type clojure.string, and instead is java.lang.String. It seems a bit odd that I need to require clojure.string to access the native Clojure string functions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `java.lang.String` is immutable and doesn't break interoperability with Java. The functions in `clojure.string` can be mostly considered as a convenience layer on top of already existing functionality in the JDK and/or `clojure.core`.

Comment: Also worth noting for the asker that `clojure.string` isn't a type, but a namespace, and `java.lang.String` is a type contained within `java.lang`.